# Cascading Combo Boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

У меня есть три связанных Combobox'a, как на этой странице:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/ClientAPI.aspx

Но в этом примере, так же, как и у меня, они работают некорректно в том случае, если нажимать F5 после выбора одного из значений бокса. Например, я выбираю страну "Монако", а в другом боксе появляется город "Монако". Затем я нажимаю F5 или кнопку обновления страницы и у меня значения страны и города остаются те же, но если сразу открыть список городов, то мы увидим все города всех стран. Соответственно, я могу выбрать город, не соответствующий выбранной стране.

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки F5 текст в комбобоксах возвращался к дефолтному состоянию.

В моей ситуации, по умолчанию, при загрузке странице ставится `SelectedIndex` = `0` и после выбора значений в боксах `SelectedIndex`, соответственно, меняются, но по нажатию F5 эти значения остаются, а `SelectedIndex` сбрасывается на `0`. В результате значение `Value` не соответствует значению `Text`.

Comment: Думал, что данная проблема возникает независимо от браузера, но, как оказалось, проблема возникает в браузере Firefox (в IE и Google Chrome работает исправно, в других не смотрел). Мне кажется это баг. Написал в devexpress, жду ответа.

Answer (score 1):

На форме необходимо прописать:

```
    <form autocomplete="off">...</form>
```

Собственно, решение было [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377301/firefox-keeps-form-data-on-reload), но я его не заметил

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Как мне кажется, это - решение; не надо редактировать вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я вижу, аналогичный вопрос уже поднимался в Саппорт Центре DevExpress. [Посмотрите тут](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T275500)

Comment: Да, поднимался мною :) Там мне как раз и ответили.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).